# If `AB->C` and `A->B` , `A->C`?

Tags: normalization

I'm new to databases, is this true? if so, how can we deduce that?
I don't know how to use the properties to get an answer, could you help>

Answer (score 1):

For each a in A, there's exactly one b in B because A->B.

So given a, we get (a,b).  And for each (a,b) there's exactly one c in C, since AB->C.

So for each a in A there's exactly one c in C.

So by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency),  A->C.

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's correct.

`A->B` => `A->AB`.

From that and `AB->C`, you can deduce `A->C` - [user993](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%e1%b5%80%e1%b4%b9)